# INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE when Upgrade Google Play Services On Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, gps

With Android Studio I'm trying to use GPS, but when calling:

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
```

the result is SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED.

After some googling I found that Google Play Services, which are installed on my emulator are old. The exact version is "versionName=6.7.74 (1723905-430)"

And according to some posts I need to download and install the latest. I tried to do this using adb and here is what is happening:

```
adb install -r com.google.android.gms-v7.3.27.apk
987 KB/s (35812914 bytes in 35.420s)
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.google.android.gms-v7.3.27.apk

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
```

Uninstall GPS doesn't work, too.

Then I tried to patch build.gradle with:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.7.74'
```

but when compile I received error:

```
Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.7.74.
Searched in the following locations:
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services/6.7.74/play-services-6.7.74.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services/6.7.74/play-services-6.7.74.jar
```

My Emulator is version 5.1, and I'm using Google API 22.

Thanks

EDIT:

I think I found a workaround! In build.gradle I have to use this dependence.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

No Idea what is new in the newer version, hope the old one will satisfy my needs.

Answer (score 4):

Use play services versions that listed in this path:

`your-android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services`

example: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'`

Comment: Yes, I found the exact same solution.